# MySQL and PHP - Get last comments from database

Tags: php, mysql, database, limit

I have this code:

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM deptcomment WHERE deptPostID ='$postID' ORDER BY deptCommentRegDate ASC, deptCommentRegTime ASC LIMIT 4";
```

It is working but it only gets the first 4 comments of a particular post. i need this code to get the last 4 comments in ASC order. Is this possible.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM deptcomment WHERE deptPostID ='$postID' ORDER BY deptCommentRegDate ASC, deptCommentRegTime DESC LIMIT 4";
```

... and then run `array_reverse();` on the result.

---

While I have you, I notice that you're constructing your query in such as way that suggests you intend on passing it on to a `mysql_*` type function. Please keep in mind that these types of functions have been deprecated, and that you are advised to use a library such as **[PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)** to communicate with the database instead.